# Potentiometer identificaiton Logitech z623 Speaker

Tags: identification, potentiometer

I've been searching and can't locate a suitable part. Perhaps due to inexperience. This is the volume control for a Logitech Z623. I believe it's 100 kΩ based off the code on the side, but cant be sure as it is broken. I found [this post](https://mattbilsky.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Repairing_Logitech_Z623_Speakers) but the one they used is not the actual part and I haven't found a datasheet, I'm trying to get nearest to OE as possible. I've read over numerous data sheets on mouser, but can't seem to find what I'm looking for. Are their any services that will help locate this?

Also if someone could explain the pin config. Given their are 6 pins, does this mean two identical outputs?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There really needs to be an electronic equipment repair stackexchange.

Comment: Is the "A104" the only marking on the pot?

Comment: Yes "A104" is all I see.

Comment: you could try to disassemble the broken pot ... replace the rivets with thin bolts ... hobby shops sell really thin hardware

Comment: Good idea, I disassembled it and found the slider is not broken, it was just the angle it popped out prevent popping back in/functioning.

Comment: Hey I know this is old and etc but Did you ever find a part?
I’m in Australia and can’t find one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Six pins means that it's a "stereo" pot, with two independent potentiometers that are ganged together mechanically.  These are almost universally arranged so that the center pin of each set of three is the pot tap, with the two outer pins being the ends of the resistive element.  The "A104" almost certainly means it's a 100k-ohm pot ("104" on an electronic component usually means \$10 \cdot 10^4\$ of whatever units of measure are important -- in this case ohms).

Beyond that, get on to the website of an electronics supplier in your country (DigiKey or Mouser in the US, Farnel in Europe, I can't help you outside of that).  Look for a 100k-ohm audio taper pot that has the same exterior dimensions as the one you have.  Be sure to get the shaft size right.  Cross your fingers, order a few, and try them out.

There's a chance that you won't find the exact thing you want, especially the details of the shaft length and dimensions of the "D".  This is because Logitech will have made enough copies of that speaker that they can economically special-order the pot to whatever specifications they want.  So you may need to get something that'll fit the board and bodge the knob mounts a bit.

Answer (score 1):

It's an old thread, but if you've stumbled upon this whilst looking for actual part numbers, here are almost drop-in replacements:

Volume pot: TT Electronics P0925N-FC20AR100K

Balance pot: TT Electronics P0925N-1-FC15BR10K (with center detent) or P0925N-FC15BR10K (without detents).